# When $\cosh (z)=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm studying complex analysis and I'm wondering about all complex values of $z$ that satisfy the equation:

$$
\cosh(z)=0 \,\, .
$$

Is there a smart way to show all values that vanish with the equation above? If yes, how could I demonstrate this? What are these values?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the definition of cosh, namely $\frac{e^{z}+e^{-z}}{2}$.

Comment: And just solve for $x+iy$? Does it work? @ChristopherHalverson

Comment: I will post a solution.

Comment: Actually it appears @YoTengoUnLCD already has.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherHalverson, please don't think I'm lazy, I just have some troubles with this properties.

Comment: @ChristopherHalverson Yes, I've added a complete solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$\cosh(z)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^z+e^{-z}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{-z}\left(1+e^{2z}\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Since $e^z$ is never zero for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, no solution exists for $e^{-z}=0$:

---

$$1+e^{2z}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{2z}=-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2z=i\pi(2n+1)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{i\pi(2n+1)}{2}$$

With $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 8):

Hint

$$\frac {e^z+e^{-z}}{2}=0 \iff e^{2z}=-1$$

Added

Let $z=x+iy$. Let $w:=e^{2z}$ then $w=e^{2z}=e^{2x+2yi}=e^{2x}(\cos2y+i\sin2y)$.

Now, just compare radius and argument with $-1$.

We have $|w|=e^{2x}=1=|-1|$ so $x=0$.

Lastly, 
\begin{align}
\arg(w)&=2y\\ \arg(-1)&=\pi
\end{align}

Then, $2y=\pi+2k\pi\rightarrow y=\frac \pi 2+k\pi$.

So we get the solutions: $z=0+\left(\frac{\pi}2+k\pi\right) i$.

Comment: All that I'm trying is vanishing with $z$ variable, I think I didn't get the idea.

Comment: @WaynerKlën I've added the full answer.

Comment: Thank mate! Now it's all more clear in my mind!

Comment: @WaynerKlën If this resolved your doubts, could you accept the answer? Thanks.

Comment: It's already accepted!