# Solve $\cosh(z) = 2$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

How can I solve $\cosh(z) = 2$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}?$
My steps have only led to values of $z$ which are not imaginary, those being $\ln(2+\sqrt3)$ and $\ln(2-\sqrt3)$. How do I find solutions to the equations that are imaginary?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625848/when-cosh-z-0

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally typed in $0$. Fixed it now

Comment: $\cosh$ has period $2\pi i$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sorry I still don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $e^{2 \pi i}=1$, if $e^x=2+\sqrt{3}$, then $e^{x+2\pi i}=e^{x+4\pi i}=e^{x+2n\pi i}....=2+\sqrt{3}$.

A similar argument for $e^{x}=2-\sqrt{3}$.

Therefore, the solutions are $\ln(2 \pm \sqrt{3})+2n\pi i$